# Imposing a cap on word count in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, sparse-matrix, text-mining

I'm analyzing song lyrics where repetition doesn't necessarily mean higher importance, so I'd like to cap the word count *per document*. For example, if a word appears `n` times in a song, where `n > threshold`, then I would replace `n`with `threshold`.

I've checked the [CountVectorizer docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), and there's an option for a `min_df` and `max_df`, but these can only disregard words that appear in some m *documents*, not words that appear n *times* in a *single* document.

I was thinking of changing the elements of the sparse matrix (say, find all elements > threshold, then replace), but I couldn't find a way to that either. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any prebuilt feature in scikit learn for this, but you could definitely edit your doc-term matrix directly, with [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for example :

```
x = numpy.where(x < threshold, x, threshold)
```

where `x` is your doc-term matrix and `threshold` is, well, your threshold.

EDIT :
I hadn't realized numpy.where didn't work on scipy sparse matrices. You can use the [`find` function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.find.html) from `scipy.sparse` that will return all non-0 indices in a sparse matrix in order to access and modify those values directly:

```
from scipy.sparse import find

results = find(x > threshold)
for i in range(len(results[0])):
    x[results[0][i], results[1][i]] = threshold
```

It's significantly less elegant but it works.